# Visual Studio 2010 shows old Visual Studio 2008 "Add Reference" dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've just noticed a very odd behaviour with VS2010.

At some point since install, it's reverted to showing the old VS2008 "Add References" dialog, instead of the fancy new VS2010 one (I do have VS2008 on this box too).

I've googled around and not found a solution.

I've tried fully resetting all options, both from Tools->Import/Export settings->Visual C# Dev Settings, and by issuing a DEVENV.EXE /RESETSETTINGS

Has anyone got any suggestions or solutions to this issue? Has anyone even seen this problem before?

**EDIT:** PEBKAC. As noted below, the "fancy new Visual Studio 2010" Add References dialog was actually a Productivity Power Tools Extension feature - which I disabled yesterday. Silly me! Thanks to all commenters

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but might really help, have you tried the productivity power tools extension? It has a really slick add reference dialogue. There are mixed reviews on the tab well and solution navigator, but it's definitely worth a download just for the new add reference. This may solve your problem.

Comment: And perhaps you used Productivity Power Tools, and recently uninstalled it? I cant recall that VS2010 have a new Add-Reference-dialog (but I'm probably so used to it that I am unable to recall the old one).

Comment: @marr75 - you've just hit the nail on the head. I was getting confused - the fancy "new VS2010 Add Reference dialog" I was referring to was actually the Power Productivity Tools dialog. I disabled the Power Productivity Tools extension yesterday to see if it was responsible for my slow VS2010 performance. Thank you for making me see my own stupidity!

Comment: @Simon Svensson - yes - you are right - spot on. DOH

Comment: Doh!  I hate it when PEBKAC stops by for a visit.

Comment: I wish, the VS2008 was better.  This background load is *not* working out well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comment, now in answer form...:

"This is not a direct answer, but might really help, have you tried the productivity power tools extension? It has a really slick add reference dialogue. There are mixed reviews on the tab well and solution navigator, but it's definitely worth a download just for the new add reference. This may solve your problem"

Comment: To be honest, while the new extension gallery and management functionality is pretty slick, it's also fragmenting what we think of as VS 2010 functionality. Would I be confused by the absence of behavior I've come to expect from my extensions after a clean install? Most likely.